# scrollTo does not scrollView

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I'm new to react-native,

I have a segment tab controller nested inside a scrollView , I'm trying to scroll the scrollView by code to show the selected segement tab in the top left of the scroll view when a segment tab is being tapped.

for some reason this is not working for me. I hard coded `x= 100` for now just for testing purposes , I see the console log of the `scroll to segment` in the debugger. but the position does not change.

I call scrollToSegment() from the onTabPress of the method of the segment tab controller.

```
scrollToSegment = () => {

    console.log('scroll to segment')
    this.sRef.scrollTo({
        x:100,
        y:0,
        animated:true
    });
};

              <ScrollView
            style={{paddingTop: 40, height: 100}}
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            ref={ref => (this.sRef = ref)}
            contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}

        >
            <SegmentedControlTab
                tabStyle={styles.tabStyle}
                tabTextStyle={styles.tabTextStyle}
                activeTabStyle={styles.activeTabStyle}
                activeTabTextStyle={styles.activeTabTextStyle}
                values={categoriesName}
                selectedIndex={currentSelectedIndex}
                onTabPress={(index) => {
                    this.scrollToSegment();
                    return onPressSegmentTab(index)
                }
                }
            />
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: try to add `contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}` to your scrollView

Comment: Change ref name from scrollRef to sRef

Comment: I'm not sure what  contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}  suppose to do but it does not work

Comment: are you having the same ref name as @BrijeshShiroya mentioned ?

Comment: Yes . it still does not work, I updated my code accordingly in the question

Comment: Can you share more code?

Comment: I added the entire return from the render method

Comment: @H.Epstein is your ScrollView nested inside another ScrollView in your componentTree ?
Another thing ... please create a ref to your scrollView using this way https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html